# How can I loop on all ul tags and implement a function on them with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, foreach, css-selectors

How can I loop on all `ul` tags with a specific class name and implement a function on them?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
$("ul.innerContainer").foreach(function(){
  //do something with the element
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `each()` not `foreach()`

```
$("ul.innerContainer").each(function(){
  //do something with the element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there:

```
$("ul.innerContainer").each(function(){
    // do something with '$(this)'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is called [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), not `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

[each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('ul.innerContainer').each(function(index) {
   //function here
});
```